# PHP. Как вытащить unix время устройства из POST запроса, на стороне сервера?

Tags: php, android, post, unixtimestamp

Android приложение отправляет POST запрос на  PHP сервер. Как вытащить из этого запроса значение unixtime устройства в момент когда оно его отправило. Понятно что время можно включить в запрос, но зачем если скорее всего оно там уже есть.

Comment: Какого устройства - клиента (время отправки запроса) или сервера (время получения)?

Comment: Да клиента, какое на устройстве было значение unix времени когда оно его отправило.

Comment: Теоретически, в заголовке HTTP запроса может быть  строка `Date: ...` с временем его формирования, но на практике клиенты ее редко делают

Comment: Как эту дату из заголовка в переменную можно вытащить?

Comment: Наверное `$_REQUEST['date']`  / Вообще, если кого-то конкретно спрашиваете, то пишите @nick для нотификации

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам timestamp нужен, то (как один из вариантов) в обработчик POST-запроса на сервере можно добавить переменную, которой будет присвоено время:

```
$time = strtotime('now');
```

Comment: `mktime` то попроще вариант будет вроде?

Comment: если я правильно понял, чел спрашивает о времени на клиенте

Comment: @teran, возможно ) php вообще довольно гибкий язык, есть разные варианты решения. просто лично я в одном из своих проектов использовал strtotime, и всё работает отлично

Comment: @qpi, а что такое "время на клиенте"? можно получить время открытия браузера с формой (если в форме прописать соответствующее скрытое поле для отправки информации о времени). а можно получить время прихода данных на сервер.

Comment: @humster_spb имеется ввиду часовой пояс клиента.
> Как вытащить из этого запроса unixtime устройства
видишь, чел спрашивает именно про время устройства. Хотя unixtime для всех одинаковый ) но кажись он именно это имеет ввиду

Comment: @qpi, тогда, видимо, надо из формы получать timestamp открытия браузера, а на сервере сравнивать это время с временем прихода данных. И если допускать, что человек заполняет форму не дольше нескольких минут, то разница в часах и покажет его часовой пояс.

Comment: @humster_spb просто `strtotome` добавляет промежуточное звено - строку. по факту это лишняя операция для получения времени.

Comment: @humster_spb зачем чтото сравнивать? о чем вы вообще говорите?)

Чел просто спрашивает, как получить время клиента)) и всё )

Comment: @qpi, как зачем? чтобы получить часовой пояс клиента

Comment: Часовой пояс клиента можно получить только двумя способами: либо клиент передаёт его явно (а перед этим юзер сам его руками выставляет где-то в настройках), либо по geoip.

Comment: @humster_spb чтоб получить часовой пояс клиента, его нужно передать на клиенте (яваскриптом как правило)
а ничего сравнивать не требуется в поставленной задаче

Comment: @qpi так я об этом и написал: передать с клиента его timestamp (без всякого js, просто в скрытом инпуте) и сравнить с timestamp на сервере - разница и покажет часовой пояс

Comment: @PinkTux по geoip получать часовой пояс нет смысла, т.к. во первых geoip не вездесущ и знает далеко не все диапазоны, во вторых разные базы геолокации (тот же максмайнд или sxgeo) одни и те же ip адреса распознают по разным странам и городам + многие используют VPN

Comment: @humster_spb 
< без всякого js
время клиентское забирать то  ты яваскриптом будешь правильно? и значение которые забрал пхать в инпут. 

> передать с клиента его timestamp  и сравнить с timestamp на сервере - разница и покажет часовой пояс

РАЗНИЦЫ НЕ БУДЕТ, timestamp он на то и таймстамп - ОН БУДЕТ ОДИНАКОВЫЙ ДЛЯ ВСЕХ! кол-во секунд с 1го января 70го года одинаковое для всех часовых поясов!!

Comment: @qpi, я не точно выразился: я имею в виду, что мы получаем локальное время клиента через инпут в форме, приводим его к формату timestamp и сравниваем с timestamp на сервере (это будут два разных числа)

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Серверная часть - это серверная часть, она ничего не знает о клиентской за исключением той информации которую передает сам клиент. А он та толком ничего не передает.

Всю информацию по окружению запроса (`request`), вы можете получить распечатав глобальную серверную переменную `$_SERVER`

Для того чтобы получить время устройства - вам нужно забрать его яваскриптом и передать в переменной на сервер.